# How can I fix the following error in KnitR?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am receiving the following error message when I run leaflet in the knitr program: ## Error in file(con, "rb"):  cannot open the connection. There is no error message, however, when I run this program in regular r. I can't figure out what the problem is. Here is the code I am trying to  use (I got it from https://www.paulamoraga.com/tutorial-geostatistical-data/#):

```
library(leaflet)
 index <- inla.stack.index(stack = stk.full, tag = "pred")$data
 prev_mean <- result$summary.fitted.values[index, "mean"]
 
 raster_prev_mean <- rasterize(x = coop, y = ra, field = prev_mean, fun = mean)
 pal <- colorNumeric("viridis", c(0, 1), na.color = "transparent")

leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
 addRasterImage(raster_prev_mean, colors = pal, opacity = 0.5) %>%
 addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal, values = values(raster_prev_mean), title = "Prevalence") %>%
 addScaleBar(position = c("bottomleft"))
```

Comment: Here is something that might or might not be the issue:  https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/708

Answer (score 0):

Did you install/include the packages from the start of the demo? Also the comment recommended you install `phantomJS` as well. If you don’t have these packages you will need to install them.

```
library(geoR)
library(phantomJS)
data(gambia)
```